# How to get the cordova jar from cordova 3.3.0?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I developed one android apps in phonegap. for that I used cordvoa 2.9.0 and developed in eclipse now I want to upgrade cordova from 2.9.0 to 3.3.0 but I am unable to find the cordova jar in cordova 3.3.0.
I am tried lot for getting the cordova jar form 3.3.0 but not got the jar.

Q.1. Is there any another way to get the cordova jar from cordova-3.3.0?

Please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that was one of my problems that I had to stay at 2.9.0 version.. if you find please tell me how.

Comment: yes I will tell you..

Comment: how you create app in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap / Cordova project structures and workflows have changed quite a bit from 2.x to 3.x versions. One of the recent changes consists in including the CordovaLib project within each newly created project instead of linking to pre-compiled .jar classes. Thus, you will not find the cordova.jar you are looking for in 3.3 version.

The most straightforward way to upgrade might be creating a new 3.x project from scratch and populate it with your existing assets/resources. It is explained in detail here (for Android):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20Android

Best.